# QStandardItem issue

Tags: c++, qt, qstandarditem

i'm having a problem with a Qlist of QStandardItems when i want to fill this QList.
This is the Error message from Qt Creator : ASSERT failure in QList::operator[]: "index out of range"

This is My code but it's temporary, the img will change every iteration.

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        QList <QStandardItem*> itemCountryFlagTab;
        QImage img =QImage(":/country/DataBase/country_flags/us.gif");
        itemCountryFlagTab.reserve(5);
        itemCountryFlagTab[i]->setData(QVariant(QPixmap::fromImage(img)), Qt::DecorationRole);
        modelTraceRoute.setItem(i, 4, itemCountryFlagTab[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Which line the error is triggered (look at the stack trace inside the debugger)?

Comment: itemCountryFlagTab[i]->setData(QVariant(QPixmap::fromImage(img)), Qt::DecorationRole);

Comment: How about creating the QStandardItems first before using them. Sorry, but this code is really really strange and wrong. And by the way: `reserve` does not work the way you expect it here since it only affects the internal buffer of the array of pointers but NOT the external (check size of the container after calling `reserve`).

Comment: I've done that but i'm getting the same behavior.This code is just experimental.

Comment: What have you done? Show us the code. This code is broken on many levels. Don't use `reserve` here - use e.g. `append` AFTER creating the items.

Comment: You're right the size is 0 even after the reserve.
what should i do to change the size.
QList does the initialization by herself, no need for fixing the size.
But still it's not working

Comment: Have you used `append`? If you want a predefined size and your objects are not that huge please use a QVector.

Comment: Reserve does not change the size. It only makes Qt alloc space for n elements in a single shot. The docs do not specify when this data will be allocated. Why you don't use the `append` method? It will surely work.

Comment: I've used QVector and i'm getting the same result.
append works like this : Mylist.append(QStandardItem)
but i want to on every iteration to save ""QVariant(QPixmap::fromImage(img)), Qt::DecorationRole"" on every item in the List.

Comment: Sorry. But you are doing strange things here. Please show the FULL code. There are two problems in your original implementation : 1) Not initialized data (just pointers to nowhere) and wrong usage of container classes.

Comment: How to initialize the QList or the QVector, they are initialized by default !!

Comment: I don't get it. You can initialize the SIZE of QVector with a given constructor (`QVector<QStandardItem*> container(5, nullptr)`). This will fix your problem with the ASSERT. But as you can see now there are just pointers to `NULL` inside the container. QList is initialized with a size of 0. You can append pointers to hopefully valid addresses to the list with `append`. If you want to use the objects the pointers are pointing to, these objects MUST exist (means: somebody must have created them BEFORE the usage). Event then: Your code still makes no sense. Please read the API on containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't initialize **itemCountryFlagTab** before using it, and thus you refer to the elements it doesn't have, and that is the source of your error. Also, you are creating **itemCountryFlagTab** from scratch during each loop iteration, so even if you initialized it, the results would be lost after the end of each loop iteration.

In short: apart from initializing the mentioned variable, you should also put **itemCountryFlagTab** declaration outside of the loop, if you want it not to be reset/vanish after every iteration.

The **reserve()** function is not used to initialize variables - it just allocates space for them so that the data of QList would not need to be reallocated over and over again in case you know how many elements are going to be appended to the list.